# How to fix this error ImportError while importing complex from ampligraph

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, package

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-449fec1eb93c> in <cell line: 28>()
     26 from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler, SMOTE, ADASYN
     27 from imblearn.under_sampling import ClusterCentroids, RandomUnderSampler, NearMiss, TomekLinks
---> 28 from ampligraph.latent_features import ComplEx
     29 

ImportError: cannot import name 'ComplEx' from 'ampligraph.latent_features' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ampligraph/latent_features/__init__.py)
```

I tried downgrading the ampligraph to fix it, but it was not working. I tried reading the document of the new version, too, but I don't know as I am new to this.

Comment: if you have access to source code then maybe you should check this file `ampligraph.latent_features` to see if it has `ComplEx` - maybe it needs some extra element to create it (some Python module or `C/C++` library).

Answer (score 0):

**`ampligraph==2.0.1` does not have `ComplEx`**

You can print and check:

```
print(dir(ampligraph.latent_features))

#output
['AbsoluteMarginLoss', 'LP_regularizer', 'NLLLoss', 'NLLMulticlass', 'PairwiseLoss', 'ScoringBasedEmbeddingModel', 'SelfAdversarialLoss', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'layers', 'loss_functions', 'models', 'optimizers', 'regularizers']
```

You can try:

```
pip install ampligraph==1.2.0
```

But, you will need old tensorflow versions to install.

https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.2.0/generated/ampligraph.latent_features.ComplEx.html#complex